# Limit Ursina FirstPersonController vertical rotation so that the horizon is always visible

Tags: python, ursina

I would like to limit the `ursina.prefabs.first_person_controller.FirstPersonController` so that **the player will always keep an eye on the world horizon.**

It comes down to limiting the angle of rotation of the camera... but how to get a valid angle?

What I have tried is:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python

import math

from ursina import camera
from ursina import window
from ursina.prefabs.first_person_controller import FirstPersonController
from ursina.ursinamath import clamp


class KeepAnEyeOnHorizonController(FirstPersonController):

 def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
  super().__init__(
   *args,
   **kwargs,
  )
  self.calculate_rotation_limit()

 def calculate_rotation_limit(self):
  half_height = window.size[1] * 0.5
  fov_half_rad = math.radians(camera.fov) *0.5
  screen_distance = half_height / math.tan(fov_half_rad)
  self.max_vertical_rotation = math.degrees(math.atan(half_height / screen_distance))

 def update(self):
  super.update()
  self.camera_pivot.rotation_x = clamp(
   self.camera_pivot.rotation_x,
   -self.max_vertical_rotation,
   self.max_vertical_rotation,
  )
```

...but it seems I've messed something up as I can still look on the ground or in the sky

Would you have a look on this?